# disable query logging - Google Appengine SDK Python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am in a situation where I have a package that is calling logging.debug(xxx).  I want to disable all logging statements by this package.  Is there a way to do that via config?

For example, every query I run is printing out in the console of the dev server:

> DEBUG:root:SELECT Entities.**path**, Entities.entity  FROM "dev~xxxx!!Entities" AS Entities INNER JOIN "dev~xxxx!!EntitiesByProperty" AS ebp_0 ON Entities.**path** = ebp_0.**path** INNER JOIN "dev~xxxx!!EntitiesByProperty" AS ebp_1 ON Entities.**path** = ebp_1.**path** INNER JOIN "dev~xxxx!!EntitiesByProperty" AS ebp_2 ON Entities.**path** = ebp_2.**path** WHERE ebp_0.kind = :1 AND ebp_0.name = :2 AND ebp_0.value = :3 AND ebp_1.kind = :4 AND ebp_1.name = :5 AND ebp_1.value = :6 AND ebp_2.kind = :7 AND ebp_2.name = :8 AND ebp_2.value = :9 ORDER BY Entities.**path** ASC

So I know how to disable it by modifying the sdk source, basically comment out the logging statement in `__StarSchemaQueryPlan`

```
logging.debug(query)
```

Is there a way to disable the logging without touching SDK code? We currently do not define any loggingConfigurations, and are using the basicConfiguror.

---

Final solution thank you @lucemia:

```
class Filter(object):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.funcName=='__StarSchemaQueryPlan' and record.module=='datastore_sqlite_stub':
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to modify the log level.

Since the module used default logger.
The following code will disable all log which's level smaller than critical.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger() # get the default logger
logger.setLevel(50) # set the skip all log which is smaller than critical (50)
```

### test case

#### a_lib.py

```
import logging

def main():
    logging.error("test")
    logging.critical('c')
```

#### a_test_case.py

```
import a_lib
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(50)
a_lib.main()
```

#### results

```
> python a_test.py
CRITICAL:root:c
```

## EDIT 1

Another way to do so is using filter

```
import logging

# define a new filter
class Filter():
    def filter(self, record):
        # extract property of record such as record.funcName, record.module
        # http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes


        if record.module == "a_lib":
            # if the record is from a module you don't want to log
            return 0
        else:
           # for record you want to log
            return 1



 # apply this filter

 filter = Filter()
 logger= logging.getLogger()
 logger.addFilter(filter)
```

Comment: I want logging, for other areas, I just dont want this package to log.

Comment: Thank you just tested it and it worked!  I updated my post above to show the funcName and module checks.

Comment: In later versions `setLevel` doesn't work. Use `logging.disable(logging.ERROR)` instead.