# How can I mute particular logs in python using logger?

Tags: python, logging

I'm struggling getting something going that should be pretty simple. I'm working on some uniittests that calls code with some very verbose debug logging. How can I tell the logging module "set everything to debug, except this one module, make it info"

Answer (score 0):

[disable query logging - Google Appengine SDK Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955651/disable-query-logging-google-appengine-sdk-python/13958187#13958187)

check the log filter, which can be used as module based filter.